# Use two jQuery carousel with two different versions of in same page

Tags: jquery, version, carousel, conflict

I want to use to jQuery carousel in same page. Those carousels use two different versions of jQuery and I cannot make both of them work at same time

Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<!-- Website template by freewebsitetemplates.com -->
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>TEST</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/smoothslides.theme.css">                   
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/infinite_carousel/simple-list.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/infinite_carousel/periscope-theme-switcher.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />  

</head>
<body>
<div>test</div>

                    <div id="slide" style="width:300px;height:300px;" >

                <div class="ss-slides">
    <div class="ss-slide">
        <img src="images/1.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="ss-slide" title="Caption">
        <img src="images/2.jpg" />
    </div>
     <div class="ss-slide" title="Caption">
        <img src="images/3.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>

            </div>  


<div class="demo">
        <h2 class="hl">Advanced example, courtesy <a href="http://www.byperiscope.com">Periscope Creations</a></h2>
            <div id="sliderBloc">
                <a id="previous">Previous</a>
                <div style="" id="slider-stage">
                    <div style="width: 512px;" id="slider-list">
                        <a class="theme"><img src="css/infinite_carousel/theme1.png" alt="Periscope angels " height="120" width="120" /><span class="nameVignette">Periscope angels </span><span class="changeTheme">changer le thème</span></a>
                        <a class="theme"><img src="css/infinite_carousel/theme2.jpg" alt="ice-cream mountains" height="120" width="120" /><span class="nameVignette">ice-cream mountains</span><span class="changeTheme">changer le thème</span></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a id="next">Next</a>
            </div>
        </div>


<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    var $j_183 = jQuery.noConflict();
    alert($j_183.fn.jquery);
</script> 

<script src="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var $j_132 = jQuery.noConflict();
     alert($j_132.fn.jquery);
</script> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/smoothslides.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.infinite-carousel.js"></script>

     <script type="text/javascript">    

       $j_183(window).load( function() {
            $j_183(document).smoothSlides({
            duration: 4000
        //     options seperated by commas 
            });
        });     

    $j_132(document).ready(function(){              
                $j_132('#viewport').carousel('#simplePrevious', '#simpleNext');  
                $j_132('#slider-stage').carousel('#previous', '#next');
            });

  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

The second carousel works perfectly with 1.3.2 version but the first one doesn't work and I have this error :

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

in this line :

```
        $j_183(document).smoothSlides({
```

how to fix that knowing that the alert dialogs display the right versions

Answer (score 1):

Include latest version of jQuery and then include **[jQuery migrate](https://jquery.com/download/#jquery-migrate-plugin)** to support older version code. Example.

```
<!-- Latest version -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.js"></script>

<!-- jQuery Migrate -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>

<!-- Use your script for both slider -->
<script>
//Your code
</script>
```

https://jquery.com/download/#jquery-migrate-plugin

Comment: with your code the first one works but thr second one did not :(  and no error in console